# How to configure bluetooth printer from the app

Tags: ios, zebra-printers

I have a zebra printer iMZ series, what I want is to check the presence of the printer and pair it through the app itself. That is, to search for any printer available in the vicinity and show the list of it. After selecting the particular one I should be able to pair it with the device.

Answer (score 0):

Brother, first you need to download Zebra printer sdk and read about how to configure your project from official website [from here](https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=WH35)

here are some helping class and project that will sure help you , figure out solution for your problem.

1. [**Zebra-Toolkit**](https://github.com/diegoCath/zebra-toolkit)
2. [**TiZebraPrint**](https://github.com/eventhero/TiZebraPrint)

Happy coding.

**edit**
please edit your  ***PLIST***
like below

```
<key>UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols</key>
<array>
    <string>com.zebra.rawport</string>
</array>
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>external-accessory</string>
</array>
```

and call your default api to search printer, and show them in a tableview.

Comment: Thanks subhash , I have the demo app of Zebra with me. What i need is having a list of bluetooth printers and letting the user to select among them and pair it with the iOS device. Not from the Settings but from within the app. Do you have any reference to that?